# Orthogonal sampling, latin hypercubes and low discrepancy sequences

Tags: sampling, monte-carlo, quasi-monte-carlo

What is the difference between each of them?

this wiki page  - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_hypercube_sampling says that:
"In Orthogonal Sampling, the sample space is divided into equally probable subspaces", which to me sounds like a property of low discrepancy sequence.

Answer (score 2):

LDS is deterministic, but Orthogonal is still based on pseudo-random. The quadrant defined in Orthogonal looks similar to LDS though.

Comment: Good answer. LDS is also called "quasi-random sequences", because it exhibits some properties similar to uniform random sequences (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-random_sequences))